# How do I get certain code to execute before every single controller action in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to check some things about the state of the session, the user agent, etc, and possibly take action and return a special view BEFORE a controller method gets a chance to execute. For example:

Most common:
User requests Home/Index
System checks to make sure x != 0.
x does not equal zero, so the Home/Index controller executes like normal.

But, sometimes:
User requests Home/Index
System checks to make sure x != 0.
x DOES equal zero. The user must be notified and the requested controller action cannot be allowed to execute.

I *think* this involves the use of ActionFilters. But I have read about them and I don't understand if I can preempt the controller method and return a view before it executes. I am sure I could execute code before the controller method runs, but how do I keep it from running in some instances and return a custom view, or direct to a different controller method?

Update: I implemented RM's solution. This is what I did:

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (myValue == wrongValue)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult{ViewName = "Notice"};
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now, when myValue is wrong, those users get the Notice view and the requested controller is never executed. To make this work I applied it to a ControllerBase that all my Controllers inherit from.

Comment: Hey chris. Let me know how did you go about it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

All depends what exactly you want to do, and how. Three options below:

---

You can use route constraints for this. They are executed when evaluating the route to match to.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeWithConstraint",
    "Home/{action}",
    new {controller="Home", action="index"},
    new { x = new MyCustomRouteConstraint () }
);

// without constraint, i.e. if above didnt pass
routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeWithConstraint",
    "Home/{action}",
    new {controller="Home", action="index"}
);
```

The MyCustomRouteConstraint type above would check for x==0 etc in your example. Not sure exactly what you want to do, but this will allow you to check conditions before running and set additional route values etc.

See [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-25-cs.aspx) for example of custom route constraints.

---

Alternativly, yes you can use a custom ActionFilter, just apply it to the controller class, and it will be called before any action is executed. Something like:

```
public class CheckXActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
           if(x == 0)
           {
               // do something
               // e.g. Set ActionParameters etc
           }
           else
           {
               // do something else
           }
      }


}
```

---

Another option is to have all you controllers (or the relevant ones) inherit from a custom controller you make, and override :

```
OnActionExecuting
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller_methods(v=VS.100).aspx) for details.

To do the same as the filter, or routing constraints.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to redirect to a different ActionMethod to show the view. Code example is in this discussion:

[Redirecting to specified controller and action in asp.net mvc action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490401/redirecting-to-specified-controller-and-action-in-asp-net-mvc-2-action-filter/1503981#1503981)