# How do you interrupt/intercept MVC Actions using ActionFilters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Feel free to close this one if it s a duplicate. I couldn't find an answer.

I wish to be able to place a `System.Web.ActionFilterAttribute` on an Action Method and override the `OnActionExecuting` method to insert business logic which determines if the Action should be fulfilled.

Can the `ActionExecutingContext` be used to cancel the executing Action Method and do one of the following:

- Send an HTTP Status Code (and the corresponding `<customError>` page).
- Execute a different Action Method within the same Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Send an HTTP Status Code (and the
>   corresponding `<customError>` page)

Almost:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
}
```

---

> Execute a different Action Method
>   within the same Controller.

Yes:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewName = "SomeOtherAction" };
}
```

Comment: I don't think the second half of your answer is correct. That will just return a different view, not execute the action.

Comment: How about `filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can always redirect to another controller/action in an action filter.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490401/redirecting-to-specified-controller-and-action-in-asp-net-mvc-2-action-filter) for an example.