# How do I redirect user to another Controller Action from an ASP.MVC 3 action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In building a custom ASP.MVC 3 Action Filter, how should I redirect the user to another action if my test fails? I would like to pass along the original Action so that I can redirect back to the original page after the user enters the missing preference.

In controller:

```
[FooRequired]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // do something that requires foo
}
```

in a custom filter class:

```
// 1. Do I need to inherit ActionFilterAttribute or implement IActionFilter?
public class FooRequired : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (TestForFoo() == false)
        {
            // 2. How do I get the current called action?

            // 3. How do I redirect to a different action,
            // and pass along current action so that I can
            // redirect back here afterwards?
        }

        // 4. Do I need to call this? (I saw this part in an example)
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);            
    }
}
```

*I'm looking for a simple ASP.MVC 3 filter example. So far my searches have lead to Ruby on Rails examples or ASP.MVC filter examples much more complicated than I need. I apologize if this has been asked before.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 Redirect From Action Filter Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/asp-net-mvc-3-redirect-from-action-filter-attribute)

Comment: That answers part of my question for sure. I didn't get that one in my search of StackOverflow before I asked. Still wondering how to pass along the existing Action.

Comment: @Talljoe and mods: More like a possible duplicate of [Redirecting to specified controller and action in asp.net mvc action filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490401/redirecting-to-specified-controller-and-action-in-asp-net-mvc-action-filter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `filterContext.Result` to a `RedirectToRouteResult`:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(...);
```

Comment: This works for me with the exception that I'm still trying to figure out how to pass along the current route so that I know which action was interrupted.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is the missing ingredient: http://www.squaredroot.com/2008/04/01/redirecttoaction-with-parameter/

Answer (score 9):

Here's a small code sample using one of my own Redirect filters:

```
public class PrelaunchModeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //If we're not actively directing traffic to the site...
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrelaunchMode"].Equals("true"))
        {
            var routeDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary {{"action", "Index"}, {"controller", "ComingSoon"}};

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeDictionary);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to intercept the route, you can get that from the [ActionExecutingContext.RouteData member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.routedata.aspx).

With that RouteData member, you can get the original route:

```
var currentRoute = filterContext.RouteData.Route;
```

Etc... Does that help answer your question?

Comment: How did you use filterContext.RouteData.Route? I tried new RedirectToRouteResult(filterContext.RouteData.Route).

Comment: how to pass data to "Index" action?