# IActionFilter Redirect in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am implementing an IActionFilter to authenticate the request in MVC3, if my authentication returns false I want to redirect the request to a different controller from within the IActionFilter.

I would like to be able to kill the processing of the current request and totally redirect the request to a different controller action.

I am also willing to use the IAuthorizationFilter but this appears for the most part the same as the IActionFilter.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this - some good ways provided here:
[Redirecting to specified controller and action in asp.net mvc action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490401/redirecting-to-specified-controller-and-action-in-asp-net-mvc-2-action-filter)

In a nutshell you can either ctx.Response.Redirect() or create a new route as the result of your filter context.

Ensure wherever you redirect to won't fail authentication though or you can get stuck in a loop unless you code in your specific url which is somewhat hacky.

If you have a problem with this, post back we'll help you out, but that should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Adam, your reference was actually the answer: @Richard  filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary {{ "Controller", "YourController" },
                                      { "Action", "YourAction" } });