# Using RedirectToAction to break out of a controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In every action in every controller, I would like to have a check that, in certain cases, would return the app to another controller/action.  I would like the check to be as simple as possible, something like `TestForExit( );`

Here's my problem:  all my actions return `ActionResult`, and here is a sample:

```
public ActionResult Partial()
{
    TestForExit( );
    ...
    return PartialView( "ViewPartial", data );
}
```

If TextForExit returns `RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" )` I have to have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Partial()
{
    var result = TestForExit( );
    if( result == null )
    {
        ...
        result = PartialView( "ViewPartial", data );
    }
    return result;
}
```

But, as I am going to have this everywhere, I'd really like to have `TestForExit( )` itself be able to send me to Home/Index rather than return an ActionResult that my Action has to return.

In other words, how can I have TestForExit ACTUALLY go to Home/Index, instead of just returning an `ActionResult` the the original Action must return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can just override the OnActionExecuting method directly in your controller class and add the logic there. This would make more sense than a custom attribute if you only need this exit logic for one particular controller.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use an custom ActionFilter.  You can apply this action filter globally.  Then in the `OnActionExecuting`, you can perform the `TestForExit` check, and redirect if needed.

For example.

```
public void TestForExitActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(TextForExit())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {{ "Controller", "ExitController" },
                                          { "Action", "ExitAction" } });
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now apply your `[TestForExitActionFilter]` attribute to your controllers, or individual actions.  Or, to add it everywhere, add the following line to `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters` `filters.Add(new TextForExitActionFilterAttribute())`.

Here are some related links.

[Redirecting to specified controller and action in asp.net mvc action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490401/redirecting-to-specified-controller-and-action-in-asp-net-mvc-action-filter)

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

Comment: Thanks.  I will keep this as a reference, although I chose a different answer that was appropriate for this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well your controller action method has to return eventually, so you still have to return an ActionResult no matter what if the action is executed.

If you want to avoid adding that code to every action, you could think about creating a [custom Action Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then marking your actions with that filter, or applying a global filter if you need it for EVERY action.

Then in your action filter, you check your exit condition and redirect if necessary.